# build.fxbuild returns error: "module not found: javafx.controls", "error: module not found: javafx.fxml" when trying to Generate ant build and run

Tags: java, javafx, build

I'm on Linux Ubuntu 21.10
My program has been running on eclipse fine, but when I want to export and use the "build.fxbuild" file in my projects file, these Errors come up:

```
[javac] warning: [options] system modules path not set in conjunction with -source 16
[javac] /home/user/eclipse-workspace/project/build/build/src/module-info.java:2: error: module not found: javafx.controls
[javac]     requires javafx.controls;
[javac]                    ^
[javac] /home/user/eclipse-workspace/project/build/build/src/module-info.java:3: error: module not found: javafx.fxml
[javac]     requires javafx.fxml;
[javac]                    ^
[javac] 2 errors
[javac] 1 warning
```

I have added the necessary VM options, the JavaFX SDK User Library to Module Path,
For some more info I'm exporting to exe, and this is when generating with build.fxbuild, not when trying to run it, not using the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Go to your module-info.java and delete everything in there except the module declaration. Now run the build.fxbuild again. There should be a new error. Its a relative error so you can take it from there.